# Css file not loading in ejs

Tags: css, node.js, ejs

Issue - I cannot figure out why the CSS file is not loading in ejs.There is no error message given by the terminal.
Its showing message -GET /assets/css/style.css 404 159 - 0.674 ms.The server (localhost is running perfectly).

What I tried :app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/assets/css'));This also gives the same message.I even tried to change the file paths and tried other methods to do so but nothing works.

My ejs code -

```
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const app = express();
const morgan =require('morgan');
const path = require('path');
dotenv.config({path:'./config.env'});
const PORT = process.env.PORT ||8080


// parse request to body-parser

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(express.json());

// log request 
app.use(morgan('tiny'));

// set view engine 
app.set("view engine","ejs");
app.set("views",path.join(__dirname,"views"))
//load assets


app.use('./css',express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,"assets/css")));

//css/style.css
app.use('/img',express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,"assets/img")));
app.use('/js',express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,"assets/js")));
app.use(express.static("assets"));

app.get('/', (req,res)=>{

    res.render('index');
    
});

app.listen(PORT,()=>{console.log('Server is running Sucessfully ');});
```

_header.ejs File

```
<html>
    <head>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href ="/assets/css/style.css">
</head>
    <body>
 <!----HEader-->
    <header id="header">
<nav>
    <div class ="text-center">
      <a href ="/" class ="nav-brand text-dark">User Management System</a>
    </div>
</nav>

    </header>
```

```
File structure
-assets

--css

---style.css
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app.use` is used to to add golbal middlewares to your routes.

The basic syntax goes like :-

```
app.use('/someRoute', middleware);
```

Instead of ...

```
app.use('./css',express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,"assets/css")));

//css/style.css
app.use('/img',express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,"assets/img")));
app.use('/js',express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,"assets/js")));
app.use(express.static("assets"));
```

Try ...

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "assets")));
```

This will serve your whole `assets` folder on the web.

The above line of code will serve your `assets` folder **along with ALL its contents** onto the web for every route your server has and will have in future.

Since now the `assets` folder is already served up, you do not actually need to add `assets` to your `href` inside your `<link>` tag.

The path to your css file is `assets/css/styles.css`.

Earlier, you server was looking for `assets/assets/css/styles.css` since `assets` is already served up.

Inside your `_header.ejs` file change the `href` of your link to :-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href ="/css/style.css">
```

Now the server will look for `assets/css/styles.css` which exists so there is no error now.

I hope this helps.

I don't understand what you were trying to do with this ...

```
app.use('./css',express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,"assets/css")));
app.use('/img',express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,"assets/img")));
app.use('/js',express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,"assets/js")));
```

Comment: No change still it's giving the same message --"GET /assets/css/style.css 404 159 - 1.721 ms"......

Comment: I have edited my answer. Your href attribute was set incorrectly. Since now assets folder is served on the server, you don't need to add that to your path.

Comment: Thanks now its working , can you also tell why the previous href was wrong ??

Comment: I'll add an explanation to my answer. You can read from there.